# Android share the text to facebook not shown in the post dialog

Tags: android, facebook, text, message

I encounter a problem, I want to share text to facebook post message dialog.

My code is below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "post message to the facebook dialog");
mContext.startActivity(intent);`
```

when I click the button , it will call the part code.

Then show the text app list.

I click the facebook app, the message just not shown in facebook app.

If I change the message to the hyperlink, It is shown in the facebook app correctly.

How to send the text to the facebook app in the post dialog?

Or have other resolve method?

Thank you very much

( my facebook app version is v1.9.2)

update: 
If can't post the text to the facebook.

How can I delete facebook share item in the app share list?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Facebook application does not handle either the EXTRA_TEXT fields https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/332619626816423

Comment: Thanks. If I wan't to hide the facebook app in the app list. Have any methods? thank you